# re.sub() does not keep blanks and new lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have an xml file with the following line :

```
           <CREATION_DATE>2009-12-20T10:47:07.000Z</CREATION_DATE>
```

That I would like to replace with the following :

```
           <CREATION_DATE>XXX</CREATION_DATE>
```

Thought it would be pretty straightforward using the `re` module in the python script I'm supposed to modify. I did something of the sort:

```
if '</CREATION_DATE>' in ligne:
    out_lines[i] = re.sub(r'(^.*<CREATION_DATE>).*(</CREATION_DATE>.*$)', r'\1XXX\2', ligne)
```

The field with the date is correctly replaced, but the trailing new line and indentation are lost in the process. I tried converting `ligne` and the result of the `sub` function to a raw string with `.encode('string-escape')`, with no success. I am a noob in python, but I am a bit accustomed to regex's, and I really cannot see what it is I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you sure something else didn't filter out the indent and trailing newline?

Comment: I am currently testing in an interpretter and it works as I intend it to, I think something is wrong upstream in the treatment of variable `ligne`...

Comment: cannot reproduce either. I've [got your script running](https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/b6603df2bcb144f5097955d0f3fa24f2) and it made what you wanted in python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative, a simpler and a more reliable way to replace the text of an XML element would be to use an *XML parser*. There is even [one in the Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> 
>>> s = '<ROOT><CREATION_DATE>2009-12-20T10:47:07.000Z</CREATION_DATE></ROOT>'
>>> root = ET.fromstring(s)
>>> root.find("CREATION_DATE").text = 'XXX'
>>> ET.tostring(root)
'<ROOT><CREATION_DATE>XXX</CREATION_DATE></ROOT>'
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, the variable `ligne` was stripped of blanks and new lines with `ligne = ligne.strip()` elsewhere in the code... I am not deleting my question though because alecxe's answer on the xml module is very informative.